# Spark - Highcharts // Add points dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, plot, highcharts, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I would like to add points dynamically to a series in spark - highcharts, precisely using Zeppelin.

I am using:

https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts

Does anybody know how to handle a chart after creating it?

Example:

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._

var myChart = highcharts(
  bank
    .seriesCol("cluster")
    .series("x" -> "x", "y" -> "y"))
  .subtitle(Subtitle("Example"))
  .title(new Title("EXAMPLE"))
  .xAxis(XAxis("X"))
  .yAxis(YAxis("Y"))
  .chart(Chart.scatter)

myChart.plot()
```

Comment: What function do you like to achieve? can you elaborate more on the real use case in your question?

Comment: I would like to do something like: myChart.addPoint(2,3,'#FF0000')

Comment: Thank you for the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For normal DataFrame, the chart data is created on the time when call `highcharts` function. The data series is created from DataFrame according the definition you put inside the `highcharts` function. It can not add data points manually.

While you can use following options to make the chart more suit for your need.

- [Add bands to xAxis or yAxis](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/blob/master/docs/DemoLineChart.md#spline-with-plot-bands)
- Add line to xAxis or yAxis. It's quite similar to plotBands
- [Add data labels](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/blob/master/docs/DemoLineChart.md#line-chart-with-data-labels)
- [Add tooltips](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/blob/master/docs/DemoLineChart.md#line-chart-with-data-labels)